# Solve equation with unknown in the denominator of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations, average

I have the following systems of equations that I would like to solve for $A$ and $B$:

\begin{align}
A&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\frac{(a_i-x+\tau A)}{B-\left(a_i-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\\
1&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\frac{-1}{B-\left(a_i-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\\
\end{align}

Is there a way to solve this equation at least one of them?

I tried something in those lines: Starting from equation $(2)$ we have:

\begin{align}
\sum_i^N\frac{1}{B-\left(a_i-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}&\equiv\sum_i\frac{1}{B-C_i}\\
&=\frac{\sum_i\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(B-C_i)\right)}{\prod_i(B-C_i)}
\end{align}
Then equation $(2)$ becomes:
\begin{align}
\implies -N&=\frac{\sum_i\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(B-C_i)\right)}{\prod_i(B-C_i)}\\
-N\prod_i^N (B-C_i)&=\sum_i\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(B-C_i)\right)
\end{align}

But this does not tell me much. Is there an obvious method to solve $A$ or $B$?

**Edit**:
$a_i$ represents the eigenvalues of a matrix. If half of the eigenvalues are $1$ and the other half $-1$ the equations then become:

\begin{align}
A&=\frac{(1-x+\tau A)}{B-\left(1-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}+\frac{(-1-x+\tau A)}{B-\left(-1-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\\
1&=\frac{-1}{B-\left(1-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}+\frac{-1}{B-\left(-1-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\\
\end{align}

Which are equivalent to solving polynomial equations.

I was wondering if the first equations could be simplified (if not solved) assuming that the sum converges.

An other way to look at it, is assuming that $a_i$ follows a distribution and $N\to \infty$. Then the equations become:
\begin{align}
A&=\int p(a)\frac{(a-x+\tau A)}{B-\left(a-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\mathrm{d}a\\
1&=\int p(a)\frac{-1}{B-\left(a-x+\tau A\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{(\tau-1)^2}}\mathrm{d}a\\
\end{align}

In that case is it possible to simplify or solve the equations?

Comment: What do you know about $a_i$?  Unless it grows faster than $i$ the first sum will not converge.

Comment: $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix. I have solved the equations above for $a_i=\pm 1$ $N$/$2$ degenerate but I was wondering if I could reduce and simplify this system for general $a_i$. If some assumptions are need in order to simplify the equations, I would still be satisfied.

Comment: If the $a_i$ are $\pm 1$ there is nothing varying (very much) in the number to be summed.  If it is not $0$, the sum will diverge.  Even if you take the $\frac 1N$ inside it will diverge harmonically unless the signs are equally $+$ and $-$.  Then it will converge conditionally.

Comment: We can assume that we choose $\{a_i\}$ such that the sum always converges.

Comment: @Matt In the case eigenvalues are 1 and -1 above, I have solved and obtained $A=(4x)/(1+4\tau)$. When you have $A$ computing $B$ is simple!

Comment: what does $\sum_i^N$ means ? are the $a_i$'s constant or do they depend on $N$ ?